# iOS How to tell the App Delegate to present a new view from the current view

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, notifications, appdelegate

I have an iPhone application that receives notifications when the user is not currently using the application. When the user clicks on the notification, they should be brought to a new view when the user opens the application as a result of opening the notification.

The delegate method within the App Delegate I will use to pass my information from the notification is:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{

//Pass my data from JSON Payload in here

//Tell current view to go to new view

}
```

I believe that a reference to a last view controller the user was interacting with before exiting the application would be a method to go about it and storing the Object in `NSUserDefaults`.

Any suggestions on how I could implement this would be appreciated.

Comment: Consider using `NSNotificationCenter` to decouple this and receive notifications for the view you're on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it with the NSNotificationCenter :) register an observer where the push should be done and fire a notification from your appdelegate. take a look to this [tutorial](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/05/16/nsnotificationcenter-tutorial-using-the-notification-center-in-your-iphone-app/) for registration and firering ;)

```
// AppDelegate
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{

    //Pass my data from JSON Payload in here
    NSObject *obj = myInformationForTheReciever;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"goToView" object:obj];
}
```

-

```
// MyViewController
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // do your stuff

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(goToView:) name:@"goToView" object:nil];
}

- (void)goToView:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSObject* myInformationForTheReciever = [notification object];
    // do stuff with that
}
```

Comment: Could you link me this tutorial please?. It would be much appreciated.

Comment: Would I have to put a receiver within every class?. When the app delegate fires a notification,how will I know which class will receive it?

Comment: every class that have registred an observer with the name that is fired ;) it's like beeing in a chatroom. you join the room (register an observer) and if someone send a message (fire a notification) you will receive it :) I will update my answer with a short example

Comment: Thanks for your example. I have something like this working at the moment but its kind of hack. I just have a single view that has already been loaded presenting a new view in a modal fashion. Initially I assumed I would need receiver in every class, due to the fact that it doesn't matter what screen I have left the app on, once I return to the app after I post the notification, I will go to a new view.

If I was to implement this feature, I would assume that I would need unique observers per class?

Comment: i think i have to know about your app and code, am a litle bit confused about this ^^ maybe there are better methods, but try it first the way you think it could go and if you stuck again, you can ask more specific questions ;) and next time i think i need more code to understand your structure, getting confused :D

Comment: Sorry for late response. You are right. NotificationCenter was exactly the thing I needed for my application. Very easy to use.